# What's the simplest way to decrement a date in Javascript by 1 day?

Tags: javascript, browser, date

I need to decrement a Javascript date by 1 day, so that it rolls back across months/years correctly.  That is, if I have a date of 'Today', I want to get the date for 'Yesterday'.

It always seems to take more code than necessary when I do this, so I'm wondering if there's any simpler way.

What's the simplest way of doing this?

[Edit: Just to avoid confusion in an answer below, this is a **JavaScript** question, not a Java one.]

Comment: Here is a function that can do both incrementing and decrementing:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29199863/4021614

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);

console.log(d);
```

Comment: this will return wrong day. under UTC -03:00, check for var d = new Date(2014,9,19)
d.setDate(d.getDate()-1); // will return Oct 17

Comment: it also returns wrong year. new Date(new Date().getDate()-1) returns 1969 for me

Comment: This doesn't decrement the date at all when i run the code snippet.

Answer (score 7):

```
 day.setDate(day.getDate() -1); //will be wrong
```

this will return wrong day. under UTC -03:00, check for

```
var d = new Date(2014,9,19);
d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);// will return Oct 17
```

**Better use:**

```
var n = day.getTime();
n -= 86400000;
day = new Date(n); //works fine for everything
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date().setDate(today.getDate() -1);
```

Answer (score 5):

`getDate()-1` should do the trick

Quick example:

```
var day = new Date( "January 1 2008" );
day.setDate(day.getDate() -1);
alert(day);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
origDate = new Date();
decrementedDate = new Date(origDate.getTime() - (86400 * 1000));

console.log(decrementedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

`setDate(dayValue)`

`dayValue` is an integer from 1 to 31, representing the day of the month.

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

The behaviour solving your problem (and mine) seems to be out of specification range.

What seems to be needed are addDate(), addMonth(), addYear() ... functions.

Answer (score 1):

Working with dates in JS can be a headache. So the simplest way is to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for any date operations.

To subtract one day:

```
const date = moment().subtract(1, 'day')
```