# javascript: how can I increment a date string (YYYY-MM-DD) by 1 day

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to do this in php with date() and mktime() functions, but have no idea how to accomplish the same thing in javascript...

```
function incr_date(date_str){
    //...magic here
    return next_date_str;
}

var date_str = '2011-02-28';
console.log( incr_date(date_str) ); //want to output "2011-03-01"
```

is this even possible with js?

Comment: go to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8295943/792103 for answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you parse it, then you use `dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)`. You'll have to parse it manually, though, or using [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) or similar; that format is not yet supported across all major browsers (`new Date(date_str)` **will not work** reliably cross-browser; see note below). And then convert it back to your format.

Something along these lines:

```
function incr_date(date_str){
  var parts = date_str.split("-");
  var dt = new Date(
    parseInt(parts[0], 10),      // year
    parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1,  // month (starts with 0)
    parseInt(parts[2], 10)       // date
  );
  dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
  parts[0] = "" + dt.getFullYear();
  parts[1] = "" + (dt.getMonth() + 1);
  if (parts[1].length < 2) {
    parts[1] = "0" + parts[1];
  }
  parts[2] = "" + dt.getDate();
  if (parts[2].length < 2) {
    parts[2] = "0" + parts[2];
  }
  return parts.join("-");
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uvace3)

Note that `setDate` will correctly handle rolling over to the next month (and year if necessary).

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uvace3/2)

The above is tested and works on IE6, IE7, IE8; Chrome, Opera, and Firefox on Linux; Chrome, Opera, Firefox, and Safari on Windows.

A note about support for this format in JavaScript: The `new Date(string)` constructor in JavaScript only recently had the formats that it would accept standardized, as of [ECMAScript 5th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) released in December 2009. Your format will be supported when browsers support it, but as of this writing, no released version of IE (not even IE8) supports it. Other recent browsers mostly do.

Comment: Are you claiming that the standard Date object constructor is not implemented consistently across browers?

Comment: @Andrea: Yes, the version of the `Date` constructor he'd need is not reliably supported yet. There was **no** standard format for `new Date(string)` prior to the 5th edition specification, which was only released about 14 months ago. Try it in any currently-released version of IE (including IE8): http://jsbin.com/omoka4

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought that ES3 would go as far as defining a few standard formats which would need to be accepted by the Date constructor.

Comment: @Andrea: Nope. All ES3 says is that it must accept whatever Date#toString spits out, and it doesn't define that, either. :-)

Comment: is this to get "01" instead of "1" for the first of the month?

Comment: should also mention this is for a webkit mobile app

Comment: @Haroldo: *"is this to get "01" instead of "1" for the first of the month?"* Yes, take a look at the live example. *"should also mention this is for a webkit mobile app"* Should work.

Comment: You should **add** one to month, not substract. And my solution is much easier, now it works in IE6, too. ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **jQuery & jQuery UI** then use the following:

```
var dt = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', '2011-02-25');
dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)
var dtNew = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dt);
```

You can [**parse**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) and [**format**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) any way you want, and most importantly you will not need a new function in your JS Library.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to turn your date string into a Date object.

```
var date = new Date('2011-02-28');
```

Then you need to add one to the day part of the date.

```
date.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
```

Although this looks it might end up with the 29th of February, it won't and will give you the 1st March.

Comment: *"`var date = new Date('2011-02-28');`"* Doesn't work in **any** currently-released version of IE (including IE8).

Comment: Yeah, because 2011 isn't a leap year.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H: Leap years don't come into it (February always has a 28th). It's the format that is new (only standardized 14 months ago) and not widely-supported yet. If you're talking about `date.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)`, JavaScript handles rolling the month (and year, if necessary) for you.

Answer (score 4):

I modified this excellent answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5116693/4021614 to handle both incrementing and decrementing by any amount (using this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/25114400/4021614).

```
function incrementDate(date_str, incrementor) {
    var parts = date_str.split("-");
    var dt = new Date(
        parseInt(parts[0], 10),      // year
        parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1,  // month (starts with 0)
        parseInt(parts[2], 10)       // date
    );
    dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + incrementor * 86400000);
    parts[0] = "" + dt.getFullYear();
    parts[1] = "" + (dt.getMonth() + 1);
    if (parts[1].length < 2) {
        parts[1] = "0" + parts[1];
    }
    parts[2] = "" + dt.getDate();
    if (parts[2].length < 2) {
        parts[2] = "0" + parts[2];
    }
    return parts.join("-");
};
```

example:

```
//increment by 7 days
incrementDate('2015-01-01', 7);
//returns '2015-01-08'

//decrement by 1 day
incrementDate('2015-01-01', -1);
//returns '2014-12-31'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use date.js from here - http://www.datejs.com/

Has lots of functions for handling this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. First you read the date and you convert to a date object, then you add 1 day and return the result

```
function incrementDate(date_str) {
    var date = new Date(date_str);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    return date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate();
}
```

The [Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), which is native in javascript, takes care of all problems arising from leap years and so on.

Comment: `new Date("2011-02-28")` doesn't work in any current version of IE. And you've dropped the zero-padding on his result string.

Comment: Uhm... I did not know that IE lacked support **even** for native objects constructors... :-( There is always something to learn about IE deficiencies!

Comment: @Andrea: The key point is that having a standard format for `new Date(string)` is **new**. JavaScript didn't have a standard format for that until 14 months ago. (That doesn't justify IE8 still not supporting it, but it rather forgives IE6 and IE7.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that lack of standardization on things such as date formats, which naturally appear in so many different flavours, is the way to hell...

Comment: @Andrea: At least it's been addressed now. You might want to remove the answer, as it'll be years before it's correct.

Comment: You forgot leading zeros and adding 1 to month. Try `new Date().getMonth()`, it will result in `1`.

Comment: I need the date like this with the zeros "2011-03-01" not like "2011-3-1"

Comment: You can use a function to customize your format. That would check whether month is less than 10, and add a 0 in case. The same for the day.

Answer (score 0):

> i hope this will help

```
function incr_date(date_str,no_of_days_to_add){
 var futureDate=new Date(date_str);

  futureDate.setDate(new Date().getDate()+no_of_days_to_add);
  var next_date_str= futureDate;

    return next_date_str;
}
```