# Auto Calculate Input Date Based on Item Type

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation

Ok, here I got one that is killing my brain.

We have backup tapes that we send off site for obvious reasons. I have created a little system that would calculate which tapes needs to come back from the storage every morning based on the return date and automatically sends out a mail with this information.

Now to make it even sweeter I have created a  little input form to capture the tape information before we send it off. What I would like to do is have the RETURNDATE field automatically calculate the return date based on the tape type (daily, monthly, weekly, yearly) but I have no idea how to do this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Below is my form. The dates are stored in YYYY-MM-DD format.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Update a Tape Record in Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{ 
$dbhost = '10.32.6.13'; 
$dbuser = 'remote'; 
$dbpass = '[cGadm1n]'; 
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass); 
if(! $conn ) 
{ 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
$tapeserial = $_POST['tapeserial']; 
$tapetype = $_POST['tapetype']; 
$dateused = $_POST['dateused']; 
$datereturn = $_POST['datereturn'];

    $sql = "UPDATE tapeman SET dateused = '".$dateused."', datereturn = '".$datereturn."', tapetype = '".$tapetype."' WHERE tapeserial = '".$tapeserial."';";

mysql_select_db('tapeman'); 
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn ); 
if(! $retval ) { die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error()); }

header("location:http://10.32.6.13/ops-center/index.php/2015-05-13-06-05-16/tape-backup-management/capture-tape-information"); 


    mysql_close($conn);}else{ ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
            <table width="750" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>Tape Serial : </td>
                    <td><input name="tapeserial" type="text" id="tapeserial" tabindex="1"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>Tape Type : </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="tapetype" id="tapetype">
                            <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
                            <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
                            <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                            <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>



                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>Date Used : </td>
                    <td><input name="dateused" type="date" id="dateused"></td>
                    <td>Date Format - YYYY-MM-DD</td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>Date Return : </td>
                    <td><input name="datereturn" type="date" id="datereturn" </td>
                    <td>Date Format - YYYY-MM-DD</td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td> </td>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>



    <?php}?>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the `datereturn` field to auto populate with a date, based on the selection made in the `dateused` field. Is this correct? If so, this would need to be done via JavaScript or JQuery.

Comment: Yes exactly, the `datereturn` would calculate based on the `tapetype` and `dateused`. can you point me in the right direction where to look at to accomplish this. Jquery and Jscript is not one of my strongest points.

Comment: Posted an answer, once jsFiddle is back online, I can add a working example.

Comment: Tapes? How old-fashioned ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry Much Old Fashioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via JavaScript or JQuery. You will not be able to really do this with PHP since the condition is based on the users selection.

jsFiddle Exmaple (a little more modular): https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6ds6vw2d/

Given your form in **HTML**, you can make a few changes:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
     <table width="750" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
          <tr align="center">
               <td>Tape Serial : </td>
               <td><input name="tapeserial" type="text" id="tapeserial" tabindex="1"></td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="center">
               <td>Tape Type : </td>
               <td>
               <select name="tapetype" id="tapetype">
                    <option value="1">Daily</option>
                    <option value="7">Weekly</option>
                    <option value="30">Monthly</option>
                    <option value="365">Yearly</option>
               </select>
               </td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="center">
               <td>Date Used : </td>
               <td><input name="dateused" type="date" id="dateused" /></td>
               <td>Date Format - YYYY-MM-DD</td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="center">
               <td>Date Return : </td>
               <td><input name="datereturn" type="date" id="datereturn" /></td>
               <td>Date Format - YYYY-MM-DD</td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="center">
               <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="center">
               <td colspan="3" align="center">
                    <input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update" />
               </td>
          </tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

First you had a few column issues. Your table uses 3 columns at times. Second, I changed the values to match the number of days for `tapetype`. Now you can use **JQuery** to make the new date for you:

```
<script>
$(function(){
     $("#dateused").on("change", function(){
          var tt = parseInt($("#tapetype").val());
          var du = $("#dateused").val();
          var parts = du.split("-");
          var date = new Date(
               parseInt(parts[0], 10),      // year
               parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1,  // month (starts with 0)
               parseInt(parts[2], 10)       // date
          ); 
          date.setDate(date.getDate() + tt); // Increment based on tapetype
          parts[0] = "" + date.getFullYear();
          parts[1] = "" + (date.getMonth() + 1);
          if (parts[1].length < 2) {
               parts[1] = "0" + parts[1];
          }
          parts[2] = "" + date.getDate();
          if (parts[2].length < 2) {
               parts[2] = "0" + parts[2];
          }
          $("#datereturn").val(parts.join("-"));
     });
});
</script>
```

This can also be seen here: [javascript: how can I increment a date string (YYYY-MM-DD) by 1 day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116657/javascript-how-can-i-increment-a-date-string-yyyy-mm-dd-by-1-day)